# AVR ISR causes unexpected behavior

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

Using avr-gcc 4.8.0 and avr-libc 1.8.0 on Arch Linux. Trying to get UART RX interrupts working on an ATtiny2313 with this simple code which should echo the received byte:

```
#define F_CPU 14745600

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600 
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

int main(){
  DDRD |= _BV(PD6);

  UCSRB = (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN);
  UCSRC = (1 << UCSZ0) | (1 << UCSZ1);

  UBRRH = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8);
  UBRRL = BAUD_PRESCALE;

  UCSRB |= (1 << RXCIE);
  sei();

  for (;;){ 
    PORTD ^= _BV(PD6);
    _delay_ms(50);
  }  

  return 0;
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect){
   char b;
   b = UDR;
   UDR = b;
}
```

I upload this with avrdude and the LED fails to pulse. If I comment out the ISR, it works as I'd expect it to. UART polling also works normally, so I'm quite sure that it is configured correctly. I've been able to reproduce this with an ATmega162 and an ATmega328p.

Other strange behavior: if I compile without optimization, the LED will pulse until I send a byte, then it stops pulsing.

I've really got no idea where the problem lies as every tutorial I've seen uses almost this exact code.

Comment: Do you need to clear the interrupt flag inside the ISR? You might be stuck in an interrupt loop.

Comment: @Samuel: The interrupt flag is automatically cleared when UDR is read. However, maybe something with the optimization goes wrong and UDR is not read? Andrew: What happens if you comment out "UDR = b"?

Comment: Check avr-gcc version 4.7.2. I have trouble finding a reference for latest stable version of avr-gcc, but most sources I checked are still on 4.7.2.

Comment: @Rev1.0: Same thing. I can comment out all three lines _inside_ the ISR, but as long as there's an ISR defined, the problem still occurs.

Comment: @jippie: I was afraid of that. Gonna try to compile 4.7.2 and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't you have a problem when you completely remove the ISR while the RXCIE is enabled? AFAIK the controller just jumps to the reset vector if no ISR target is available.

Comment: @Rev1.0: Yeah, that does make sense, but it runs normally if the ISR isn't there. That is, as soon as I use the macro, it gets all screwy.

Comment: Something is very wrong there. Is the uC hanging or permanently rebooting? Did you try using [BADISR_vect](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html#ga1f6459a85cda682b2163a20af03ac744) to see if any unexpected ISR is fired? Is there even any external UART communication going on?

Comment: See answer below. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I hate myself for this. How I was compiling:

```
avr-gcc -o build/src/main.o -c -Wall -g -Os -mmcu=attiny2313 src/main.c 
avr-gcc -o build/main.elf build/src/main.o
```

How I should have been:

```
avr-gcc -o build/src/main.o -c -Wall -Os -mmcu=attiny2313 -std=c99 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections src/main.c
avr-gcc -o build/main.elf -mmcu=attiny2313 build/src/main.o
```

The actual culprit was not passing the `-mmcu` flag to the linker, but adding `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` also cured some weird problems I was having when using external header files.

Comment: GLad to hear you fixed it. But I would investigate why using "-ffunction-sections and -fdata-sections" just "cured some weird [other] problems". Maybe due to code size? Because the linker is able to remove unused functions (sections) this way.